# Can one give riba to their poor sibling?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, money

If we have siblings who are NOT SO financially fit and need extra help in terms of money then in that case can one sibling being financially sound give his/her riba to the other sibling?

Comment: Erm.. I think no. Any form of riba is forbidden in Islam, regardless of the connection between the ones that did it. You don't want to make your sibling in an even more harmful problem do you?

Answer (score 1):

From an Islamic perspective, the involvement with Riba is in 4 ways:

1. To take riba
2. To give riba
3. To prepare an agreement or business contract that deals with riba
4. To sign as a witness for a rib-based transaction.

So if you're involved in either of these, you get the same punishment and it is the same evil.

Therefore, you should not give rib funds to anyone. There is no reward in this, but sin.

If you really want to help someone and get the rewards from Allaah, give what is pure.

If you can't help financially, pray for the poor person.

I hope this is clear.